# ForEach not working on mongodb but it work fine in locally array declaration

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

[error of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hV189.png)

My forEach loop is not working in ejs file while trying to fetch data from data base (mongodb) it contain a collection namely campground.but it work fine when I stored a collection of object in a array in myapp.js code.but when i m trying to implement through storing data in database it shows a error of **campground.forEach is not a function**

Here is my code:

**myapp.js**

```
var express=require("express");
var app=express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/campit");
var campgroundSchema=new mongoose.Schema({
  name:String,
  image:String
});

var campground=mongoose.model("campground",campgroundSchema);
app.get("/create",function(req,res){
   campground.find({},function(err,campgrounnd){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      else{
        res.render("index.ejs",{campground:campground});
      }
    })
 });
app.listen("3000",function(){
  console.log("listening from server 3000"); 
});
```

**index.ejs file which is suppose to render and it contain that for.Each loop**

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <% campground.forEach(function(camp){ %>
      <div class="col col-lg-4 img-thumbnail">
        <img class="but" height="75%" width="100%" src="<%=camp.image%>" alt="image">
        <div class="text-center">
          <h6><%= camp.name %> </h6>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info " type="button" name="more info"> more info</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% }); %>
  </div>
</div>
```

any help will be highly appriciated..**thank you**
[console.log the campground](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdvC8.png)

Comment: can you please add the error that you are getting

Comment: please have a look at the starting of question

Comment: put this line console.log(campground), just before res.render("index.ejs",{campground:campground});, and see whats getting printed.

Comment: it is showing a lot of  json data i don't know from where it come to my collection should i post the image of that??

Comment: please post I think you are getting mongoDB cursor in campgrounnd.

Comment: please check the ending of question :)

Comment: try changing this line campground.find({},function(err,campgrounnd){.. to
campground.find({},null, function(err,campgrounnd){....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The find method in MongooseJS returns a Query object (reference). There are a few ways you can do searches and return results.

```
   campground.find().exec(function(err,result){
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      else{
        res.render("index.ejs",{campground:result});
      }
   });
```

Comment: where are you trying to access result?

Comment: in the index.ejs file...i also replace  the campground with result in  index.ejs file

Comment: No there you still have to access it as campground, as you can see I am still passing it as campground here --- res.render("index.ejs",{campground:result});

Comment: yes it works:) :) :) :) finalllllllllllllly but i didn't understand that.exec part why it is used?? and whats wrong with the initial code?

Comment: Please mark answer as correct an upvote if it worked for you, Please read the docs for detailed explanation http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Answer (score 0):

I think you are conflicting variable name

```
var campground=mongoose.model("campground",campgroundSchema); // here is a campground
app.get("/create",function(req,res){
   campground.find({},function(err,result /* <-- */){ // the result is also campgrounnd
      if(err){
        console.log(err);
      }
      else{
        res.render("index.ejs",{campground:result/* <-- */}); // pass result instead campgrounnd
      }
    })
 });
```

Comment: have you `console.log(result)` ?? Is the result same as you attached image in the question??